# Stop cmdloop() from stripping white space from the input line in python

Tags: python

My code looks something like this in short:

```
class myClass(cmd.Cmd):

  def do_myFunction(self, line):
    print line+'!'

if __name__ == '__main__:
  myClass().cmdloop()
```

When I use this on the command line and type a line with whitespace at the end, the cmdloop() readline seems to automatically strip them so instead of printing:

```
myline !
```

it prints:

```
myline!
```

Does anybody know a way around this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible without rewriting the whole module. Why would you want that behavior?

Comment: what happens if you use `print line,"!"` ?

Comment: @Noelkd: OP clearly wants the real whitespace that was input, not just a sinlge space in the output no matter what was input.

Comment: He might just want a single white space, but your right my answer wasn't **the** answer hence the comment instead.

Comment: It looks like overriding the `parseline()` method and doing essentially the same thing it does now but removing the calls to `.strip()` will fix it without needing to rewrite the entire module...

Answer (score 2):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

"It looks like overriding the `parseline()` method and doing essentially the same thing it does now but removing the calls to `.strip()` will fix it without needing to rewrite the entire module..."

~ answer courtesy of [Wooble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble)

Comment: You can find the source code for `parseline` here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a63c61168588937c482435d0432c753de4844c46/Lib/cmd.py#L172

Answer (score 0):

You should spacing out a space at line 4 like this:

```
print line+' !'
```

instead of:

```
print line+'!'
```

The extra space in the string will 'push' the ! away form the rest of the string. I hope this helps you!